# How to enable Install Via USB in Xiaomi Redimi Note 4?

Tags: android, xiaomi

I want to test the android app using android studio on Xiaomi Redimi Note 4 (MIUI Global 8.5) Phone. When i try to click the Install Via USB, it says the device is temporarily restricted 3-3 error. I have enabled USB Debugging.

I tried using VPN from google but it didn't worked. I also installed Plex VPN and tried to connect to China - Shanghai Server, but it says VIP plan and purchase it. I couldn't purchase it.

I couldn't find any solution to solve this error. Excepting solution from here..

Comment: Do you enable developer option from settings

Comment: I had some troubles with a xiaomi device too... I solved like this:
Enable developer options -> enable usb debugging, enable install using usb, then Disable Miui optimization (on my device is the last selection in dev opts)

Comment: yes.i have enabled..

Comment: I'm using Xiaomi mi5. This is my settings:

Developer options (yes)
USB debugging (yes)
Install via USB (yes)
Turn on MIUI optimization (yes)

Comment: can u give me the idea..

Comment: I have turned on usb debugging and turned off MIUI Optimization

Comment: Enable "install via usb" too, let us to know if one of us answers works

Comment: anything i tried isn't working. Always it gives same error "the device is temporarily restricted 3-3"

Comment: So, I want the solution from here that really works..

Comment: Ok, try to disable WiFi and switch install via USB on while you are connected through data and under your xiaomi account.

Comment: yes..i have done this but not working..

Comment: You can try downloading a non-official plexvpn apk!

Comment: can some provide me the link of non-official plexvpn app

Comment: I think we can't provide for non-official app's link here!

Answer (score 0):

***Automated way***

first of all download [this](https://www.vpngate.net/common/openvpn_download.aspx?sid=1538063929096&tcp=1&host=49.4.1.77&port=443&hid=11559063&/vpngate_49.4.1.77_tcp_443.ovpn) .ovpn file.

Then download on your phone OpenVpn app.

Open the app, click on OVPN Profile, select the file previously downloaded and press import, then press add.

Now you have added the vpn connection with his relative settings, now switch on the button referred to the vpn connection in the section "OVPN profiles".

***Manual way*** Open your vpn settings -> add a new vpn.

Fill these fields:

```
-Name: something
-Type: L2TP/IPSec PSK
-Server address: 49.4.1.77
-Pre-shared key: vpn
-Select show advanced options
-Forwarding routes: 0.0.0.0/0
-Username: vpn
-Password: vpn
```

The .ovpn file and the server address points to a chinese vpn that you can find on https://www.vpngate.net/en/

Comment: It says unsuccessful..not connecting

Comment: You have to wait just a little bit for connection!